# Aligned struct not available globally

Tags: c, pointers, struct, alignment, draw

I have a small bare metal program for the Raspberry Pi which draws to the screen.
I am using C, with GCC as the compiler, and Yagarto as the ARM tool chain.

Currently, I have a header (gpu.h) which declares the frame buffer structure, which the GPU reads (it contains resolution and bit depth). The GPU fills in values in the structure, including a pointer to draw to:

```
struct frame_buffer {
    int width;
    int height;
    int vwidth;
    int vheight;
    int bytes;
    int depth;
    int ignorex;
    int ignorey;
    int pointer;
    int size;
};
extern struct frame_buffer framebuf;
```

The structure is defined in main.c (not within a function):

```
struct frame_buffer framebuf __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = {GPU_HRES, GPU_VRES, GPU_HRES, GPU_VRES, 0, GPU_BITDEPTH, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Also in main.c is a function to draw a character to the screen (draw_char), and my own implementation of putchar(), which uses the draw_char function. Currently this is working fine.

If I move the draw_char function to another file, everything compiles OK, but nothing is drawn to the screen.

I think the structure is not available globally, so the pointer is not correct.

Any ideas on what I should do to fix this?

Thankyou

Comment: If `draw_char()` compiles fine but is not using the `framebuf` you're setting up within your `putchar()` then several possibilities can cause this: **1.** Your `putchar()` is not writing to the "global" `framebuf` that `draw_char()` is using, **2.** Once-moved `draw_char()` is no longer using the "global" `framebuf` you're writing to in `putchar()`, **3.** Possibly your `putchar()` is no longer using the `draw_char()` you think it is. Check for local vars named `framebuf` as a start. I'd start hunting there.

Comment: aligned (16) definition is not visible from another c file. Try to add it to extern frame_buffer declaration/

Comment: putchar() doesn't actually change framebuf. It just makes calls to draw_char(), and it writes individual pixels (in 16-bit increments) to the pointer provided by the GPU. There is another function which initially requests the pointer from the GPU (once off). The GPU stores the address in the structure itself. This function is already in another .c file.
Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give enough information to actually solve your problem, but the above comments very likely are right - either the data structures are different or the functions. I can give only some suggestions how to find the reason, which helped me in the past for similar issues:

1) Use `objdump` (gcc toolchain) or a similar tool and check the object files what they require and what they export. Each function and structure should exist only in a single object file (and it should be imported from the others).

2) Verify if there is a library function which has same name and is taken in linking stage (the name `putchar()` is very dangerous here). The C linker does not verify arguments (unlike the C++ linker). Be sure that the linker takes your objects first and later the libraries. For most compilers/linkers the order of arguments is relevant.

3) Rename the variable individually in the files and headers and check if the code still compiles. The unmodified files should not compile.

4) Add debug statements which give you the address of functions and variables. The address of the variable should be always the same when running the software (I assume you find another possibility to output debug texts beside your display functions).

5) You say the pointer is acquired - verify that it really is the same allover the code and be sure the values do not get overwritten.

Sorry, no more ideas.